# The Cauchy integral formula of complex functions of several complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading [Daniel Huybrechts' Complex Geometry](http://www.im.ufrj.br/%7Eandrew/ensino/VC20-1/Huybrechts-Complex_Geometry.pdf). In chapter 1 (page 5, proposition 1.1.2) he generalized the Cauchy integral formula as follow: 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^{n}}\int_{|m_i-w_i|=\varepsilon_i}\frac{f(m_{1},m_{2},\dots,m_{n})}{(m_{1}-z_{1})(m_{2}-z_{2})\dots(m_{n}-z_{n})}\mathrm{d}m_{1}\mathrm{d}m_{2}\dots \mathrm{d}m_{n}$$

I am curious about what is the definition of this multi-dimensional complex integral? Indeed, I have check several textbooks on this topic, but none of them give a definition. And I can only intepret it as the iterated line integral of single variable complex function.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful to have a look at the first chapter of the  book "Tasty Bits of Several Complex Variables" by Jiri Lebl . Which has a very good explanation.

Comment: I will read the book.@yi li

Answer (score 3):

The $k$th coordinate projection can be considered as a function $m_k:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$, and then $dm_k$ is just the differential of this complex-valued function.  Explicitly, if the real and imaginary parts of the $k$th coordinate are $x_k$ and $y_k$, $dm_k$ is the complex-valued $1$-form $dx_k+idy_k$.  Then $dm_1\dots dm_n$ is the complex-valued $n$-form which is the wedge product of all these $1$-forms, and so the integral in question is given by pulling this $n$-form back to the $n$-dimensional submanifold $T^n\subset\mathbb{C}^n$.

(When $n=1$, this coincides with the usual definition of path integrals with respect to $dz$, since pulling the $1$-form $dz$ along a path $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ will give you $\gamma'(t)dt$.  As a result, in your example where you are integrating over $T^n$, the $n$-dimensional integral can also be obtained by iterating such $1$-dimensional integrals, by Fubini's theorem.  But the definition above using $n$-forms makes sense more generally for integrating on arbitrary smooth $n$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^n$, even ones that are not just a product of paths on each coordinate so that there is not any obvious way to turn them into iterated integrals.)

Comment: This definition makes sense to me. Could you exlpain in detail how can I apply Fubini's theorem ? Since this is integral of differential forms on a manifold, T^{n} is not technically a product of measure space, the application of Fubini theorem seems not very straightforward.

Comment: I think I have figured out how to apply Fubini's thorem. Since T^{n} is very special, it can almost be covered by a single chart (the obvious one). Apply Fubini in this coodinate. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that would work.